# regex replace words with certain number of chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace all words with desired number of chars:
Have this string:

```
Down the Rabbit Hole Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank and of having nothing to do once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading but it had no pictures or conversations in it and what is the use
```

How I can remove all words with 3 chars or less from above string?

```
$data = preg_replace( "/[\w+{0,3}]/m", '', $data );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
preg_replace("/\b\w{1,3}\b/", '', $data);
```

Comment: +1 And if you're worried about having multiple spaces after removing short words, a second replacement such as `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data)` could do the trick.

Comment: @greenbandit `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Without it, three word characters in the middle of a word would match (so you'd remove "Dow" from "Down", which is obviously not desirable).

Comment: Have other question: how I can remove words too long? I mean if word has 8 or more chars.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$data = "Down the Rabbit Hole Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank and of having nothing to do once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading but it had no pictures or conversations in it and what is the use";
$data = preg_replace( "/\b\w{1,3}\b/", '', $data);
echo $data;

# Down  Rabbit Hole Alice  beginning   very tired  sitting   sister   bank   having nothing   once  twice   peeped into  book  sister  reading     pictures  conversations    what
```

Comment: In which way is it different than @MichaelRushton answer?